# IRQ Numbering Conflict

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, bios, interrupt-handling

From: 
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-pc-architecture/

Exception number 10h corresponds to a "Floating Point Error" but software interrupt 10h also corresponds to "Video support" BIOS interrupts (both in real mode).

What am I missing?

Comment: IRQ conflict?  How *old* is this hardware?

Comment: The OP does not understand the difference between the software interrupt and the hardware one, and asks for clarification (and I am curious too for a good answer... +1)

Answer (score 6):

You're not missing anything.

The 8088 processor (the one used in the original IBM PC) only defined exceptions 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

So IBM used 0x8 to 0xF for hardware interrupt handlers and 0x10 and above for BIOS routines. For some reason IBM ignored the fact that Intel had very clearly *reserved* numbers 0x5 to 0x1F for future processor exceptions.

As time went on, more exceptions were needed and Intel went ahead and assigned them. Most of the time, legacy software didn't trigger these exceptions anyway whilst newer operating systems (those that ran in protected mode) could assign different numbers so as not to clash with the processor exceptions.

There were plenty of hacks added to older software to gain some use of newer processor features without breaking too much compatibility. While I'm not sure, I suspect that perhaps newer BIOSes might have tried to detect whether INT10 was triggered by a software interrupt or by the coprocessor in their INT10 handler.

FYI, from the 386 programmers manual:

> > Coprocessor errors vector to interrupt 16. Any 80386 system with a coprocessor must use interrupt vector 16 for the coprocessor error exception. If an 8086/8088 system uses another vector for the 8087 interrupt, both vectors should point to the coprocessor-error exception handler.

Comment: Interesting. So basically every time the 387 raised an interrupt, it used the same interrupt line for the BIOS, and the OS multiplexed it accordingly ?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not sure. asveikau has another good theory under 'edit 2'. Note that this is only really related to DOS (and anything else that runs in real mode) - this isn't a problem for protected-mode systems such as Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

OK, have a look [here, on Watcom's site](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Math_error_handling_on_x87#8087_in_the_IBM_PC_and_XT).  This is the important part I think, although the old note about the 8087 is interesting too.

> Due to the market reality of the vast
>   majority of PC users still running PC
>   DOS and requiring IBM PC
>   compatibility, the way the IBM AT
>   handled math errors was not
>   straightforward. Because IBM ignored
>   Intel's recommendation when designing
>   the PC, 286's Math Fault or interrupt
>   16 conflicted with BIOS video service
>   interrupt 10h (16 decimal). On top of
>   that, existing software expected math
>   exceptions to arrive through INT 2.
>
> Instead of connecting the CPU and FPU
>   ERROR pins, the IBM AT used
>   motherboard circuitry to route the 287
>   ERROR signal to the cascaded second
>   8259A PIC and used IRQ 13 to signal
>   math errors to the CPU. The default
>   BIOS IRQ 13 handler (that is, INT 75h
>   vector - remember that IRQ 8, the
>   first IRQ line of the second PIC,
>   corresponds to interrupt vector 70h)
>   contains code to invoke INT 2 for
>   compatibility with existing software.
>   Software on the AT thus still can hook
>   the NMI vector and run unchanged on
>   the PC or AT.
>
> External circuitry in the IBM AT
>   drives the 286's BUSY input pin active
>   when a 287 asserts its ERROR signal.
>   This prevents execution of further FPU
>   instructions and is required to avoid
>   problems in the time window after the
>   287 signaled an error and before the
>   time the 286 starts processing the
>   resulting interrupt.

Comment: But these days the coprocessor is part of the same chip as the processor! I wonder whether Intel went with their own designs or bowed down to PC compatibility . . .

Comment: @Artelius, also from the Watcom page: "By the time the i486 was released (1989), Intel had realized the importance of the PC compatible market. Therefore the i486 contains features designed specifically to provide compatibility with existing PC software and hardware designs".  How's that for "reverse logic"....

Answer (score 2):

The floating point fault is a CPU interrupt, generated by an error condition.  This is different from an IRQ.

The PIC (Programmable Interrupt Controller) can be used to modify which IRQs will get mapped to which CPU interrupt.  If you send the PIC's IO port the proper sequence (using the `OUT` instruction), you can map the IRQ in such a way that it doesn't conflict with the CPU interrupt from a floating point exception.

See also [this document](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/pdf/pic.pdf).

**EDIT:** But now that I read your question again...  We're not talking about IRQs here.  BIOS Int 10h is a different beast altogether...  It's some code that your BIOS has implemented for video routines.  If you're writing an OS and wondering if you should handle floating point faults, you should probably forget this particular BIOS interrupt exists.  :-)

EDIT 2: Come to think of it, probably the way old DOS programs worked around this was to backup the IVT entry, put their own exception handler in its place, did some floating point ops, and restored the old IVT entry when they were done with the FPU.

Comment: The way a real IBM PC/AT got around this was that they didn't tie the co-processor error to the CPU directly. To avoid this conflict apparently Intel recommended to IBM that the best approach was to route the co processor error into a PIC where it is treated as an external interrupt. That is the purpose of IRQ13 on PC/AT (and later). To remain compatible with 8087 FPUs that tied the co-processor error to the NMI (Int 2h) the IBM PC/AT BIOS would install an IRQ13 handler (int 75h) that would jump to the vector at int 2h. That meant int 10h was free to be used for video services like the PC/XT

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that the `int 10h` Floating Point Error is a protected mode exception, while the `int 10h` BIOS Video Services is a real mode interrupt.

> 

The happy answer is that clearing the `NE` bit in the `CR0` register will prevent the exception from occurring and allow it's use in PM32 as a simple interrupt (*for example in a 32 bit protected mode BIOS extender*).